# Замена background-image в email рвссылках

Tags: html, css, рассылка, background-image

Смотрел https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNCaCDFKJfc на 5:28 и на 13-й строке написано, что не нужно использовать background-image, потому что outlook не поддерживает. Что можно использовать вместо background-image?

Comment: Ну, тег img, например?

Comment: background-ы outlook поддерживает. Он не поддерживает их позиционирование и свойство no-repeat. А так, в оутлуке есть куча email-шаблонов с background-ами. Просто вся поддержка довольно специфична. Раньше шаблон верстали таблицей, где в каждую ячейку прописывали кусок background-а. Вся эта таблица складывалась в один большой пазл.